# Can any real be found in an interval of $\left(\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n\right)$$ covers $(0, 1)$.

To do that, I want to prove that for every real $x$ there exists an interval $\left(\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n\right)$ that will contain $x$. I'm not sure how to do that, or if it's even true, although I suspect it is. I can use the Archimedian property to show that there exists $n$ (or $n+1$) such that $\frac 1 n < x$ but I don't know where to go from there.

One idea that popped into my mind is to use contradiction. Suppose there exists an $x$ that is not contained in such an interval. Then unless $n = n+1$ there would be a hole in the reals. I don't know how to translate that into math and make it rigorous though.

Comment: You might have meant to write $(\tfrac{1}{n+1},\tfrac{1}{n})$ instead of $(\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{n+1})$ since $\tfrac{1}{n+1} < \tfrac{1}{n}$ for every positive integer $n$. Also, the number $x = 1/2$ isn't in any of those intervals. Nor is $x = 1/3, 1/4, 1/5,$ etc. You would need to modify the set to be something like $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left[\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ to cover $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing there is type error (cause the correct is $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$), if $x\in (0,1)$, then $\frac{1}{x}>1$. Set $y=\frac{1}{x}$. The integer part of $y$ is the $n$ searched (it is natural number cause $y>1$). This proves one contention.

The other is trivial.